# PHP on Azure: how to list blobs in a 'folder'

Tags: php, blob, azure-blob-storage, subdirectory

I'm trying to list all blobs contained in the 'accidentsPhoto' 'folder' located at the root of the blob container:

```
// List blobs.

    $key = 'accidentsPhoto';
    $blobListOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
    $blobListOptions->setPrefix($key);
    $blobListOptions->setDelimiter("/");

    $blobList = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs($blobContainer, $blobListOptions);

    foreach($blobList->getBlobPrefixes() as $key => $blob) {
        echo "BlobPrefix ".$key.": \t".$blob->getName()."\n";
    }

    foreach($blobList->getBlobs() as $key => $blob) {
        echo "Blob ".$key.": \t".$blob->getName()."\t(".$blob->getUrl().")\n";
    }
```

Alas, only the key is listed as follows:

```
Set-Cookie: XXXX
Date: Tue, 15 Aug 2017 12:42:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

BlobPrefix 0:   accidentsPhoto/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to **remove** the following line to list blobs.

```
$blobListOptions->setDelimiter("/");
```